# Matching two columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup

I am having trouble getting excel to match two columns.

I have 3 columns in total, 1 is blank, 2 contains a list of companies and 3 contains another list of companies.

I want to match column 3 with column 2 to see which clients are present in both columns. Unfortunately column 2 contains data that may be slightly different from column 3. i.e Column 2 will have a company called

> F Public Works Ltd

but Column 3 will contain

> F Public Works

I believed that Vlookup was the answer, and might still be.

What I had was in column 1 `=VLOOKUP(B2,B$2:C$500,3,TRUE)`

B2 = Column 2

B$2:C$500 = Both Column 2 and Column 3.

3 = Column 3

TRUE = Because the data might not be exact but will still reference the name of the company in some way. I think this is how this will work. Let me know if I am incorrect.

I hope this makes sense, If someone could help me out with this, that would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Your column number should be 2 as this is relative to your data and not to your sheet, column A does not exist in your formula, column B is therefore 1 and column C is 2. Give that a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: you may also look for partial matching of strings. check this [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3642-excel-lookup-partial-match.html), it explains how to do that.